# Unable to type * asterisk in BulletedList <ul> while answering and asking quesion

Tags: support, markdown

I'm unable to type * asterisk in BulletedList  while answering and asking question.

Please find below screenshot for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use a [Backslash Escape](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash) to escape the `*` with a `\` as follows:

```
- \* aa
- bb
```

Output:

- * aa
- bb

---

Source [Markdown: Syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash)

> **Backslash Escapes**
>
> Markdown allows you to use backslash escapes to generate literal
>   characters which would otherwise have special meaning in Markdown’s
>   formatting syntax. For example, if you wanted to surround a word with
>   literal asterisks (instead of an HTML  tag), you can use
>   backslashes before the asterisks, like this:
>
> ```
> \*literal asterisks\*
> ```
>
> Markdown provides backslash escapes for the following characters:
>
> ```
> \   backslash
> `   backtick
> *   asterisk
> _   underscore
> {}  curly braces
> []  square brackets
> ()  parentheses
> #   hash mark
> +   plus sign
> -   minus sign (hyphen)
> .   dot
> !   exclamation mark
> ```

Comment: @Rahul The reason you have to do this is because the `*` is used as another character for lists. So seeing `- *` at the front of the line, it thinks you're trying to start a list inside a list.