# Link in comments does not allow brackets

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

I often cite from links pointing to MSDN and I do it like this:

```
see [AssocGetPerceivedType [MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
```

which results in

*see [AssocGetPerceivedType [MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*

However, linking in comments, additional brackets are not allowed and the link gets malformed like this:

[image: broken link in comments]

Comment: Testing brackets: [Foo [MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Testing parentheses: [Bar (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Maybe you can use parentheses instead of square brackets?

Comment: Testing brackets: [Foo \[MSDN\]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: [FooBar \[MSDN\]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Escape `\\`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to type \* asterisk in BulletedList <ul> while answering and asking quesion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287786/unable-to-type-asterisk-in-bulletedlist-ul-while-answering-and-asking-quesio)

Comment: I had the same bug with parenthesis

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can escape square brackets with a leading backslash `\`, so:

```
[AssocGetPerceivedType \[MSDN\]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
```

becomes:

[AssocGetPerceivedType [MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

*even in comments* (see below).

Comment: **Without backslashes**: [AssocGetPerceivedType [MSDN]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). **With backslashes**: [AssocGetPerceivedType \[MSDN\]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Any reason why I should escape them in comments and not in posts? This does not follow the principle of least astonishment. For me, this is a temporary workaround, not a solution.

Comment: @Thomas the [comment formatting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) simply doesn't support the full mark-up of actual posts (if you click `help` while writing/editing a comment it calls it *"mini-Markdown"*).

Comment: @Thomas: You _should_ do it in posts, too. You're just getting lucky there.

Comment: Clearly you should make links in posts worse, so that users are not surprised when links in comments don't work the same?