# Link formatting in comment sometimes not working

Tags: support

I have used link formatting in comments often and sometimes it doesn't format correctly, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35034959/3664960)

I searched for formatting problems like [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291676/3664960), but that isn't my problem.

My problem is that it sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't, even after editing multiple times.

I think I'm doing something wrong but I can't find it.

I thought the format should be [text to display](link or url you want to add)

I don't have any brackets in the text to display so the other meta post isn't relevant for me.

Comment: you miss the http in front of the site. [this is wrong](some.site.com) but [this will work](http://some.site.com)

Comment: easy as PI!!! Thanks. I usually don't add the http because it doesn't matter most of the time. Tested and it's working, could you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex checks if you have a protocol in your link.

> `[this will not work](some.site.com)`

because it considers some.site.com not to be meant as an valid url.

> `[this will work](http://some.site.com)`

will be converted to a link because what is in between the parenthesis is valid and complete url.

example of above markup in a comment:

[image]